# Network Settings in Linux -> Multiple IPs

Tags: networking, network-interface, dhcp

I'm not by any means an expert on networks nor Linux. And I'm trying to solve a network related issue in Linux.

I have a server that I want to make accessable in two different networks (local network and another network).

So I need my Linux system to have 2 different IPs right?

- one in the local network `192.168.1.xx`
- one given by a DHCP server.

I have made changes in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file in a way to make this possible:

```
auto eth0 eth0:0
allow-hotplug eth0 eth0:0

iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.35
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.1

iface eth0:0 inet dhcp
```

And this does work. The problem is when the device is only connected to the local network (there is no DHCP server) the Linux system is not accessible via the local static IP. Right in the moment that I connect the device to the other network (where a DHCP server is present) it starts being accessible with the local static IP. I guess that there is no logical reason why this is this way. Are the network setting worng?

Extra question:
Can I make it in a way that the system can only aquire a IP from a pre-determinated DHCP server? (So that if there are more that one DHCP servers in different networks, the system aquires an IP from the right DHCP server)

Thanks :)

Comment: Please explain how the "local network" and "another network" are related, include a diagram if necessary. Giving a single computer two addresses in the same LAN segment is not how you do this, whatever your setup is. What you need to do instead depends on your setup.

Comment: The more common way to do this would be to talk to your network administrator and have them configure the gateway/router system to establish proper routing between the "local network" and the "another network". Having multiple DHCP servers in the same physical network segment is going to end badly unless the configurations of all the DHCP servers are specifically designed to cooperate with each other. ("End badly" might mean an angry network administrator locating and removing any rogue DHCP servers from the network.)